# Dataframe to text file with column names

Tags: r, text-files

I have a dataframe with a larger data and columns than shown below:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3),
                 B = c("DD", "EE", "FF"))
```

I'd like to convert this data frame to a text file, but the content of this file should be like this:

```
A 1  
B DD  
  
A 2  
B EE  
  
A 3  
B FF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapply` to paste the data in required order and use `cat` to write it to text file.

```
cat(paste0(c(t(mapply(paste, names(df), df))), 
             collapse = '\n'), file = 'result.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
write.table(
  do.call(rbind, lapply(asplit(df, 1), function(x) rev(stack(x)))),
  file = "a.txt",
  quote = FALSE,
  col.names = FALSE,
  row.names = FALSE
)
```

where `a.txt` contains

```
A 1
B DD
A 2
B EE
A 3
B FF
```